# Beamer error driving me nuts

Tags: beamer, errors, verbatim

OK, I've been staring at this for an hour.  I know there's an error in this frame, as the document compiles fine if I put `\end{document}` in the frame before this.  But this frame gives an error

```
File ended while scanning use of \next
```

Where is it?????

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{PROC TEMPLATE for a fancy graph (part 1)}
\begin{alltt}
proc template;
 define statgraph scatdens2;
 begingraph;   *BEGIN DEFINING THE GRAPH;
   entrytitle "Scatter plot with density plots";
    *CREATE A TITLE;
   layout lattice/columns = 2 rows = 2
    columnweights = (.8 .2) rowweights = (.8 .2)
      columndatarange = union rowdatarange = union;
   *LAYOUT LATTICE...SETS UP A GRID OF GRAPHS;
   *COLUMNWEIGHTS AND ROWWEIGHTS SETS
    THE RELATIVE SIZE OF THE INDIVIDUAL COLUMNS AND ROWS;
 \end{alltt}
 \end{frame}
```

Comment: should be fixed with https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/0c387deb21263aff6bc4864618e3cb74dcf32357

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Believe it or not, the error was caused by the space before `\end{frame}`.

Comment: Oh, I believe you. `frame` is a pseudo-environment, i.e. a macro in disguise which collects everything till `\end{frame}`. With the `fragile` option it turns on verbatim mode in addition and then looks for the `<new line>\end{frame}` *verbatim*. With the space it doesn't find it and therefore takes everything until the end of the document where an error is raised, except of course if there is such a line later in the document.

Comment: what's the point of adding the [fragile] option ?

Comment: That's scary... thanks! Unbelievable is the perfect translation for "not easy findable" in this case.

Comment: @ViniciusMassuchetto After more than one year I don't remember precisely what I did to pinpoint the error. I was probably helped by the fact that I *never* indent environments. :) Only the code in definitions and sometimes the *contents* of the environments, particularly "continuation lines" in tabulars.